# How to connect internet automatically during startup?

Tags: ip, networkmanager, router

The os recognize my ethernet device as `enp6s0`.

```
ifconfig -a
enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
```

My home network structure:

```
isp ---- moden ---- router ---- pc
```

I had already binding my pc mac address with `192.168.31.22` in router setting,router ip locates `192.168.31.1`.
Everytime i boot pc ,it can't connect the internet automatically,i have click connect button on wcid network manager gui.
[image]
It is no use to set the `/etc/network/interfaces` as below:

Setting as static ip.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback   
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet static
address 192.168.31.22
netmask  255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.31.1
dns-nameservers  192.168.31.1
```

setting as dhcp.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback   
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: In addtiion to @showkey answer, you may have to comment out "auto enp6s0" after you add "allow-hotplug  enp6s0".

Answer (score 0):

Add the line in  /etc/network/interfaces.

```
allow-hotplug  enp6s0
```